# Apache echarts scatter: assign label to each point

Tags: echarts

I am building an echarts scatter graph that contains 6 points. I would like to manually assign a label to each point, like I did with the label of X and Y axis.
Is there a way to achieve this? I searched in Apache Echarts docs but I did not find any useful setting for assigning a label to "data" values.

Here is the source code of my graph:

```
    option = {
  xAxis: {
    data: ['Low', 'Med', 'High'],
    name: "Value",
  },
  yAxis: {
    min: '5',
    name: "Score",
  },
  series: [
    {
      type: 'scatter',
      symbolSize: 20,
      data: [
            [2,9.8],
            [1,8.8],
            [2,5.9],
            [1,9.8],
            [1,10.0],
            [3,9.8],
            [2,10.0],
            [1,9.8],
            [2,5.9],
            [1,9.8]
            ],
      label: {
      show: true,
      position: 'right',
      color: "black",
      fontSize: 16,
      },
    }
  ],
  grid:{
    show: true,
    backgroundColor: new echarts.graphic.LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 1, [
    {
      offset: 0,
      color: 'rgb(255, 102, 102)'
    },
    {
      offset: 1,
      color: 'rgb(153, 255, 153)'
    }])
},
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could specify the labels as an additional value in the data array:

```
data: [
    [ 2, 9.8, "label1" ],
    [ 1, 8.8, "label2" ],
    ...
```

Then use a formatter function in your label definition, to select the third element of the data array as the label:

```
label: {
  ...
  formatter: function(d) {
    return d.data[2];
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I also found this solution, working as well as Chris one:

```
 series: [
    {
      type: 'scatter',
      symbolSize: 15,
      data: [
        {value: [2,9.8] , name: 'value1'},
        {value: [1,8.8] , name: 'value2'},
        {value: [2,5.9] , name: 'value3'},
        ],
      label: {
      show: true,
      position: 'right',
      formatter: params => params.name,
      color: "black",
      fontSize: 16,
      },
```